# Error when trying to run a keycloak image from docker-hub with podman

Tags: keycloak, podman

I am using the following podman command to run the image on port 8083:

```bash
podman run --name=keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -p 8083:8080 jboss/keycloak
```

I get the following Output from console:

[image: Console Output]

When I go to localhost:8083 I get a 404 - Not Found